# How to add context setters in a Reactjs context object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a Typescript library that is a Reactjs context provider.

I want to pass "context setters" in the context, to the consumers.

I'm facing this error:

> error TS7022: 'setHelpState' implicitly has type 'any' because it does
> not have a type annotation *and* is referenced directly or indirectly in
> its own initializer.

(my italics)

however... the state setter is clearly typed:

```
type AddFlowFunction = (id: FlowId, showInitially: boolean) => void;

type State = {
    flows: FlowStates;
    useHelpFlow: AddFlowFunction;
    // ... similar for other state
};

type StateSetter = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<HelpTypes.State>>;

type UseHelpState = [HelpTypes.State, StateSetter];

export const useDynamicHelpState = () => {
    const [helpState, setHelpState]: UseHelpState =
        React.useState<HelpTypes.State>({
            flows: {},

            useHelpFlow: (id, showInitially) =>
                _useHelpFlow(setHelpState, id, showInitially),
    });

    return helpState;
};

// provided this way:

    <div className="App">
        <DynamicHelp.DynamicHelpProvider
            value={DynamicHelp.useDynamicHelpState()}
        >
```

I wonder - does this error message mean "or" when it says "and"?   It is in fact simply not allowed to do this?

How should I enable context consumers to update the context in a controlled way?

Comment: As a quick note, have you considered doing Redux? I did something similar with Contexts, but migrated to Redux and it's been a lot easier to work with.

Comment: ~~Yes, thanks, at the moment I want to avoid forcing Redux on the consumer of the library (but I'm open to being convinced I should just do that).~~  Actually if I'm honest, I'm balking at learning Redux :facepalm: Either way, I'd like to get to the bottom of that error message.

Comment: hehe, that's fair. Redux did seem like a lot of a hassle at first, but after reading through the tutorial and actually using it, it was easier than I expected. Though I definitely get wanting to reduce dependencies.

Can you include the type definition for HelpTypes in your question?